# SSIS Lookup data update

Tags: ssis

I have created a SSIS Package that reads data from a CSV file and loads into table1 . the other data flow tasks does a look up on table 1 .Table1 has columns x , y, z, a ,b  . Table 2 has columns a , b ,y,z Lookup is done based on columns y and z . Based on the column y and z , it is picking up a and b from table 1 and updating table 2 . The problem is the data gets updated but i get multiple rows of data thats is one without updation and one after updation .

I can provide more clear explanation if needed .

Comment: please provide the needed help experts!

Comment: You definitely need a clearer explanation. What does 'one without updation and one with updation' mean? Perhaps you should learn to do this in an update statement instead of fiddling in SSIS

Comment: 'one without updation and one with updation' mean means I have a data row  Event_ID Model_Dsc Model_Cd Derivative_Cd VIN Length (cm) Width (cm) Height (cm)
1 L405 Range Rover T1  QVBW NULL NULL NULL NULL Afer Updation - Event_ID Model_Dsc Model_Cd Derivative_Cd VIN Length (cm) Width (cm) Height (cm)
5 L405 Range Rover T1  QVBW NULL 5199 2073 NULL  Ideally I should only get 1 row , the second row .

Comment: Describe how your package is performing the update.    Aside from the CSV source, and the lookup, what other components are in your data flow?

Comment: I have 2 data flow tasks . Data flow task1 is reading a csv file and loading into table 1 .Data flow task2 is taking source as table2 then data conversion then lookup based on to columns Code and description . Based on the lookup , picking up values of length , width and height from table 1 and filling table 2 .  I hope I am clear . Please appreciate your help.

Comment: So your dataflow task is using Table2 as a Source, and sending rows to itself (Table 2).   Well that should produce duplicate rows.  What are you trying to do, and why are you doing it that way?

Comment: we would create a SSIS Package to read a CSV file on the Server and populate (Model_Desc , Mode_code, DERIVATIVE_CD, VIN NUMBER ,OUT_GATEDATE , DISTRIBUTION_CD, POL_CD , POD_CD ) JLR_Events table.  The Dimensions as Length , Width ,Height , Transit Height , Transit Cube will be populated from JLR_MODEL DIMS . This is the requirement. Can you suggest what is the best way to do it then .

Answer (score 0):

Fleshing out Nick's suggestion, I would get rid of your second data flow (the one from Table 2 to Table 2).

After the first Dataflow that populates table 1, then just do an EXECUTE SQL task that performs an UPDATE on Table 2, and joins to Table 1 to get the new data.

EDIT in response to comment:

You need to use a WHERE clause that will match rows uniquely.  Apparently `Model_Cd` is not a UNIQUE column in `JLRMODEL_DIMS`.   If you cannot make the WHERE clause unique because of the relationship between the two tables, then you need to select either an aggregate `[Length (cm)]` like `MIN()`, `MAX()` etc, or you need to use `TOP 1`, so that you only get one row from the subquery.

Comment: UPDATE  JLR_EVENTS 
SET [Length (cm)] = (SELECT [Length (cm)]
               FROM JLRMODEL_DIMS 
               WHERE JLR_EVENTS.Model_Cd = JLRMODEL_DIMS.Model_Cd); Problem with the query ..Error- Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Thanks , It works fine with TOP1 . I wonder why couldn't I do it . Anyway , thanks for your help . Truly a gem!!

Comment: Hi Tab , When I deply the JOb on Server , It says File not found .Any idea . Thes erver does not have MS Excel installed on it bit that package pecks up a CSV file from the path and writes to a databse . Help would be much appreciated

Comment: You need to open a new question so you can supply more details specific to this issue.

Comment: Hi Tab , Have posted a separate question . Please see .